# It is giving me undefined local variable error?

Tags: ruby

Not sure why this is giving me an error of

> "`greet': undefined local variable or method `name' for # (NameError) from `'

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet(other_name)
    "Hi #{other_name}, my name is #{name}"
    return other_name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `name` is a local variable only available in the constructor. To reference it as an instance variable in the greet method, use `#{@name}` instead of `#{name}`.

Comment: Do you mean?  class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
  
  def greet(other_name)
    "Hi #{other_name}, my name is #{@name}"
    return other_name
  end
en

Comment: @Amidabrian, yes. However, I'm guessing you want to either return that value or print it. If you want to return it, delete the last line (`return other_name`). If you want to print it, put `puts` in front of the string: `puts "Hi #{other_name}, my name is #{@name}"`.

Comment: Thanks for your help